# Cubic root of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

how can I find a matrix A such that $B=A^3$ where $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 12 & 0 \\
0 & 8 & 12 \\
0 & 0 & 8
\end{pmatrix}$$

I tried it working on the characteristic polynomial of $A$, but given that it's $f(t)=(8-t)^3$ then the only eigenvalue of $B$ is 8. What I wanted to do is to write $B=QDQ^{-1}$ where $D$ is the Diagonal matrix but I couldn't. I already know that $A$ must be equal to $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 &-1/2 \\
0 &2&1\\
0&0&2 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Any sugestions?

Comment: $\sqrt[3] A = 2\exp(\log(A/8)/3)$.

Comment: One approach is to use a power series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice self-contained approach. Let $I$ denote the identity matrix, and write
$$
N = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}.
$$
Your matrix is
$$
B = 8I + 12 N.
$$
I claim (as a "guess") that the cube root of this matrix can be written in the form
$$
A = a_0 I + a_1 N + a_2 N^2.
$$
Noting that $N^3 = 0$, we expand $(a_0 I + a_1 N + a_2 N^2)^3$ to get
$$
B = A^3 = a_0^3 I + 3a_0^2a_1 N + 3a_0(a_1^2 + a_0a_2)N^2.
$$
It now suffices to solve the system
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0^3 = 8\\
3a_0^3a_1 = 12\\
3a_0(a_1^2 + a_0a_2) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You better double-check your expansion of $A^3$ ... and the back substitution ($a_0^3=8$)!

Comment: @greg Thanks for catching that; fixed it